How do I set scope in Azure API Manager (APIM) when using D_application_id
Trying to use Application ID to control access to function apps by adding a identity provider to the app, and when I do it in a logic app, pointing to the function app, and add authentication as follows it works.
            "HTTP": {
            "inputs": {
                "authentication": {
                    "audience": "c0e13b97-14f1-430f-bdba-a9651502e8e4",
                    "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "www.replaced.com/api/get_time"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "runtimeConfiguration": {
                "contentTransfer": {
                    "transferMode": "Chunked"
                }
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },

So tried to set it up in API Manager so it would use its Application ID, and found the following on the MS Support site:
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="AD_application_id" output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
    <!--Application (client) ID of your own Azure AD Application-->
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"])</value>
    </set-header>

It seems to send something, but the problem is that it seems to be missing scope, or as the error message reads from the tracce:

authentication-managed-identity (0.081 ms)
{
"messages": [
null,
"Getting Managed Service Identity token for AD_application_id audience threw exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: [MSAL] Authentication failed for ClientId: 2ea6156a-a72f-4a7e-bbaa-8cb2f1002ad1 Certificate: D6E1D650CAFDC108F524C69055892889F1EEC9F1 AuthorizationUrl: https://login.windows.net/6147eb36-9fd8-4609-b472-1d18921607e3 resourceId: AD_application_id ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope AD_application_id/.default is not valid. Trace ID: ad5bd488-f5e2-45e5-8d8c-d20acf1d0c00 Correlation ID: 211218e5-be38-457c-a6ed-0a321426bfeb Timestamp: 2024-09-18 14:03:52Z\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ThrowServerException(HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.CreateResponse[T](HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.d__13`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Utils.StopwatchService.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Gateway.Policies.Identity.ActiveDirectory.Msal.MsalAadClient.d__12.MoveNext() in C:\__w\1\s\Proxy\Gateway.Policies.Identity\ActiveDirectory\Msal\MsalAadClient.cs:line 115\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Gateway.Policies.Identity.ActiveDirectory.Msal.MsalAadClient.d__12.MoveNext() in C:\__w\1\s\Proxy\Gateway.Policies.Identity\ActiveDirectory\Msal\MsalAadClient.cs:line 147\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.Configuration.Models.ManagedIdentityResolver.d__16.MoveNext() in C:\__w\1\s\Proxy\Gateway.Policies.Identity\ManagedIdentityResolver.cs:line 134'.",
"[MSAL] Authentication failed for ClientId: 2ea6156a-a72f-4a7e-bbaa-8cb2f1002ad1 Certificate: D6E1D650CAFDC108F524C69055892889F1EEC9F1 AuthorizationUrl: https://login.windows.net/6147eb36-9fd8-4609-b472-1d18921607e3 resourceId: AD_application_id",
"AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope AD_application_id/.default is not valid. Trace ID: ad5bd488-f5e2-45e5-8d8c-d20acf1d0c00 Correlation ID: 211218e5-be38-457c-a6ed-0a321426bfeb Timestamp: 2024-09-18 14:03:52Z"
]
}

But I have no clue where to find the scope or figure out how to set it, and can't find any useful documentation, anyone had any luck with this?

Are you using client_id or client_id/.default in resource? You need to use client id. @vrghost

You need to use client_id instead of client_id/.default in the resource of authentication-managed-identity policy.
I am using the same policy with the given value in it.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="c2660*****878ea5" output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"])</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
</policies>

I am getting expected response.



That was absolutely spot on, thank you so very much
